# What does the ngc command do in an angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I just came across this command in a tutorial and I am struggling to find any information on the ngc command. Can anyone shed some light please?

ng build --prod && ngc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's related to Angular Template Compiler.

`ngc` is a drop-in replacement for `tsc`.

As per repo doc:

> ## First install angular, see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02
>
> $ npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
>
> ## Optional sanity check, make sure TypeScript can compile.
>
> $ ./node_modules/.bin/tsc -p path/to/project
>
> ## ngc is a drop-in replacement for tsc.
>
> $ ./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p path/to/project

You can find complete description [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/packages/compiler-cli#install-and-use)